# Server cached 302 redirect rule from ht-access file and redirect all visitors to wrong page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We were upgrading our server so we used the following code in HT-ACCESS file located in the root folder of the server to redirect users to update.php page until we finish our work:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/in-update.php$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !40.255.207.189
    RewriteRule $ /in-update.php [R=302,L]
```

After we finished the update we removed this code from the ht-access file but the server still redirect the users to the update page

the ht-access file also contain the following code:

```
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
```

Any body can help how to fix this problem?

Comment: There's no way to fix this. User's have to clear cache. Next time do not redirect the users client but rewrite internally serverside to show the maintenance-site.

Comment: OMG !!! this will kill my site rank !!!

Comment: Can you positively determine if "server still redirect the users to the update page" or users have it cached?

Comment: users have it cached because new users open the site normally ...

Comment: Try rewrite from /in-update.php to /update.php until you see logs with in-update.php requests.

Answer (score 0):

the only way i found is to edit the in-update.php file and put text to notify users to empty there browsers cache